# Why do i get Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

I'm new at this, and having some trouble with my code. The thing is, it works, but i keep gettingthis "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" when i check my exercise in jet brains. But in my IDE it does work. This is the exercise = 
"Write a program that reads two numbers a
a
 and b
b
from the keyboard and calculates and outputs to the console the arithmetic average of all numbers from the interval [a;b]
[
a
;
b
]
, which are divisible by 3
3
.

In the example below, the arithmetic average is calculated for the numbers on the interval [−5;12]
[
−
5
;
12
]
. Total numbers divisible by 3
3
 on this interval 6
6
: −3,0,3,6,9,12
−
3
,
0
,
3
,
6
,
9
,
12
. Their arithmetic average equals to 4.5"

The program works and returns the 4.5.

This is my code:

```
        int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    double divisible = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double num =0;

    for (double i = a; i<b; i ++) {
             num = in.nextInt();
        if (num%3==0) {
            divisible = divisible +1;
            sum += num;
        }

    }

    double result = sum/divisible;
    System.out.println(result);
```

Hope u can help me because I really wanna improve my skills and keep learning. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You read a lot of numbers there. You should only read 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
double count = 0;
double sum = 0;

for (double i=a; i<=b; i++) {
    // Check if number is divisible by 3
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        // Count total numbers
        count += 1;
        // Calculate sum
        sum += i;
    }
}

double result = sum / count;
System.out.println("Average: " + result);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Removed `num = in.nextInt();` as `i` in `for (double i=a; i<=b; i++)` will get all numbers between `a` and `b`.
2. Replaced `sum += num;` with `sum += i;`.

Comment: Oh I see it now, I didn't have to make a variable to take in the inputs, the command "for" does the work when the condition is accomplish. Lol, so dumb. Thank you so much I will keep this in mind next time!